# Navigation issues

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I am building my new Vaadin application for Prototype using the link https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+a+simple+login+view

I have 3 views

1) Login View
2) Main View
3) Registration View

and

1)  base class LoginUI.java which handles the navigation.

So, to put together, I have a Login View which is the main login screen and has 2 buttons, one to Login to application and another one to Register a new user.

and these 3 views are handled by a base class called LoginUI.java

The problem I am currently facing is that I am successfully able to login to application i.e. the navigation from Login View to Main View is perfectly  fine. But, when I click Register button, the navigation does not take me to Registration View at all. It still holds me at Login View (instead of navigating to Registration View).

Could some one please help me here?

I believe the problem is mainly in **beforeViewChange** method in LoginUI.java

But am unable to fix it

The classes are as below

**1) LoginUI.java**

```
public class LoginUI extends UI {

@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = LoginUI.class)
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

    //
    // Create a new instance of the navigator. The navigator will attach
    // itself automatically to this view.
    //
    new Navigator(this, this);

    //
    // The initial log view where the user can login to the application
    //
    getNavigator().addView(SimpleLoginView.NAME, SimpleLoginView.class);

    getNavigator().addView(RegistrationView.NAME, RegistrationView.class);
    //
    // Add the main view of the application
    //
    getNavigator().addView(MainView.NAME, MainView.class);

    //
    // We use a view change handler to ensure the user is always redirected
    // to the login view if the user is not logged in.
    //
    getNavigator().addViewChangeListener(new ViewChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean beforeViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {

            // Check if a user has logged in
            System.out.println("getSession().getAttribute(\"user\") is " + getSession().getAttribute("user"));
            boolean isLoggedIn = getSession().getAttribute("user") != null;
            boolean isLoginView = event.getNewView() instanceof SimpleLoginView;

            System.out.println("isLoggedIn is " + isLoggedIn);
            System.out.println("isLoginView is " + isLoginView);

            if (!isLoggedIn && !isLoginView) {
                // Redirect to login view always if a user has not yet
                // logged in
                //getNavigator().navigateTo(SimpleLoginView.NAME);
                getNavigator().navigateTo(SimpleLoginView.NAME);
                return false;

            } else if (isLoggedIn && isLoginView) {
                // If someone tries to access to login view while logged in,
                // then cancel
                return false;
            }

            System.out.println("Returning True");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

**2) Login View**

```
public class SimpleLoginView extends CustomComponent implements View,Button.ClickListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final String NAME = "login";

private final TextField user;

private final PasswordField password;

private final Button loginButton;

private final Button regButton;

public SimpleLoginView() {
    setSizeFull();

    // Create the user input field
    user = new TextField("User:");
    user.setWidth("300px");
    user.setRequired(true);
    user.setInputPrompt("Your username (eg. joe@email.com)");
    user.addValidator(new EmailValidator(
            "Username must be an email address"));
    user.setInvalidAllowed(false);

    // Create the password input field
    password = new PasswordField("Password:");
    password.setWidth("300px");
    password.addValidator(new PasswordValidator());
    password.setRequired(true);
    password.setValue("");
    password.setNullRepresentation("");

    HorizontalLayout panel = new HorizontalLayout();
    // Create login button
    loginButton = new Button("Login", this);
    regButton = new Button("Register", this);
    panel.addComponent(loginButton);
    panel.addComponent(regButton);
    panel.setSpacing(true);

    // Add both to a panel
    VerticalLayout fields = new VerticalLayout(user, password, panel);
    fields.setCaption("Please login to access the application. (test@test.com/passw0rd)");
    fields.setSpacing(true);
    fields.setMargin(new MarginInfo(true, true, true, false));
    fields.setSizeUndefined();
    fields.setStyleName(Reindeer.LAYOUT_BLACK);


    // The view root layout
    VerticalLayout viewLayout = new VerticalLayout(fields);
    viewLayout.setSizeFull();
    viewLayout.setComponentAlignment(fields, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    viewLayout.setStyleName(Reindeer.LAYOUT_BLACK);
    setCompositionRoot(viewLayout);
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    // focus the username field when user arrives to the login view
    user.focus();
}

@Override
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    if (event.getButton().equals(loginButton))  {
        boolean validate=validateLogin();
        if (validate)   {
            getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(MainView.NAME);
        }
        else    {
            Notification.show("Username/Password provided is incorrect");
        }
    }
    if (event.getButton().equals(regButton))    {
        System.out.println("Invoking Registration View");
        getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(RegistrationView.NAME);
    }

};

public boolean validateLogin()  {
    if (!user.isValid() || !password.isValid()) {
        return false;
    }

    String username = user.getValue();
    String password = this.password.getValue();

    //
    // Validate username and password with database here. For examples sake
    // I use a dummy username and password.
    //
    boolean isValid = username.equals("test@test.com")
            && password.equals("passw0rd");

    if (isValid) {

        // Store the current user in the service session
        getSession().setAttribute("user", username);

        // Navigate to main view
        //
        return true;

    } else {

        // Wrong password clear the password field and refocuses it
        this.password.setValue(null);
        this.password.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

**3) Registration View**

```
public class RegistrationView extends CustomComponent implements View,Button.ClickListener {
public static final String NAME = "Registration";
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final Label feedback;
private final TextField username;
private final PasswordField password;
private final PasswordField verifyPassword;
private final TextField name;
private final TextField email;
private final Button registerBtn;
private final Button clearBtn;
private VerticalLayout fields = new VerticalLayout();
public RegistrationView() {

    feedback = new Label();

    username = new TextField("Registration");
    username.setWidth("300px");
    username.setNullRepresentation("");

    password = new PasswordField("Password:");
    password.setWidth("300px");
    password.addValidator(new PasswordValidator());
    password.setRequired(true);
    password.setValue("");
    password.setNullRepresentation("");

    verifyPassword = new PasswordField("verifyPassword:");
    verifyPassword.setWidth("300px");
    verifyPassword.addValidator(new PasswordValidator());
    verifyPassword.setRequired(true);
    verifyPassword.setValue("");
    verifyPassword.setNullRepresentation("");

    name = new TextField("Name");
    name.setWidth("300px");
    name.setNullRepresentation("");

    email = new TextField("Email");
    email.setWidth("300px");
    email.setNullRepresentation("");
    email.setInputPrompt("Your email (eg. joe@email.com)");
    email.addValidator(new EmailValidator(
            "Email Address"));

    HorizontalLayout buttonLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    buttonLayout.setSpacing(true);
    registerBtn = new Button("Register", this);
    buttonLayout.addComponent(registerBtn);

    clearBtn = new Button("Cancel", this);
    buttonLayout.addComponent(clearBtn);

    fields.addComponent(feedback);
    fields.addComponent(username);
    fields.addComponent(password);
    fields.addComponent(verifyPassword);
    fields.addComponent(name);
    fields.addComponent(email);
    fields.addComponent(buttonLayout);
    fields.setStyleName(Reindeer.LAYOUT_BLACK); 
}


public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    if (event.getButton().equals(registerBtn)) {
        Notification.show("Registered user");
    }
    else if (event.getButton().equals(clearBtn)) {
        activated();
        Notification.show("Clear all the fields");
    }
}

public void activated() {
    username.setValue("");
    password.setValue("");
    verifyPassword.setValue("");
    name.setValue("");
    email.setValue("");
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    username.focus();
}
}
```

**4) Main view**

```
public class MainView extends CustomComponent implements View {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final String NAME = "";

Label text = new Label();

Button logout = new Button("Logout", new Button.ClickListener() {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

        // "Logout" the user
        getSession().setAttribute("user", null);

        // Refresh this view, should redirect to login view
        getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(NAME);
    }
});

public MainView() {
    setCompositionRoot(new CssLayout(text, logout));
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    // Get the user name from the session
    String username = String.valueOf(getSession().getAttribute("user"));

    // And show the username
    text.setValue("Hello " + username);
}
}
```

Comment: isn't this comment ``// Redirect to login view always if a user has not yet logged in`` basically explaining your problem?

Comment: Yeah my bad, thanks..

Got the problem though.. I needed to add the below condition.

boolean isregView = event.getNewView() instanceof RegistrationView;